# Encouraging Cross-Site SE Questions

Tags: feature-request

I think as we graduate, it's good to encourage visits from related sites, particularly Physics.SE, Biology.SE, etc.

I often find some questions on Chemistry.SE that could easily be on Physics and vice-versa.

I'd like to encourage supporting a [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199989/build-and-strengthen-the-stack-exchange-community-with-crossover-questions-bet) feature request for sharing questions between multiple sites.

This proposal would offer an alternative to migrating questions. Instead for topics (e.g., quantum chemistry) that are shared between sites, questions could become "crossover" questions and appear on multiple SE sites.

What do you think?

Comment: See also (from our own Manish): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131950/asking-on-multiple-sites-soft-migration.

Comment: Sorry that your proposal got closed on MSE.  This is an overall a great idea and I hope (and have hoped for a long time) that we can look into something for this purpose.

Comment: Oh, there are clearly a lot of duplicates, so it's no big deal. I'm surprised they didn't come up when I searched, but everyone seems to use different terms for the same idea.